# VBA set "PrintObject" property false, inlinecode

Tags: vba, excel, properties, inline-code

I created a ActiveX Button in my SourceCode and locade it.
After that I changed the Caption protery and get it an click event.
Now I have to change the "Print Object" property inside my Source Code.

But I don´t know how.

I tried that one:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects((22 + counter)).Object.PrintObject= False
```

(22 is the index from the Button)

and

```
Dim rangeString As range
Dim name As String
name = "J" & verifyRow & ":" & "K" & verifyRow
Set rangeString = ActiveSheet.range(name)
Set obj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=rangeString.Left, Top:=rangeString.Top, Width:=rangeString.Width, Height:=rangeString.Height, PrintObject:=False)
```

But nothing works.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, you even didn't ask one.  Also "*I can't find anything about that*" means that you even didn't use Google because [Button.PrintObject Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.controls.button.printobject.aspx) is the first result if you google for "PrintObject". Show us what you tried to do (e.g your code) what it actually does and what you expect it to do. See [ask] for help how to write a good question.

Comment: I´m sorry. I know I can change this property in the PropertyView from this object. But i want to set this Property in my SourceCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CommandButton1").PrintObject = False
```

where `CommandButton1` is the name (not the caption) of your button.

Or if you like to use indices

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(1).PrintObject = False
```

as written in the references: [Button.PrintObject Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.controls.button.printobject.aspx).

---

Instead of `ActiveSheet` I recommend to use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` to fully specify the worksheet.